# TreeView with multi-color TreeNode text

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, treenode

I need to have the text within a node in TreeView to be colored within words or characters. Is that possible? What is the way to go? I heard of Custom Drawing but have no experience with it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the property of the TreeView:

```
treeView1.DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
```

Then from the DrawNode event:

```
private void treeView1_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e) {
  Color nodeColor = Color.Red;
  if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) != 0)
    nodeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;

  TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics,
                        e.Node.Text,
                        e.Node.NodeFont,
                        e.Bounds,
                        nodeColor,
                        Color.Empty,
                        TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
}
```

More from MSDN: [TreeView.DrawNode Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode.aspx)

Comment: How could I change this so half of the node.text is red and the other half is of default color (black)

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Which half?  Do you mean two words?  One red, one black?

Comment: Yes exactly it would be two words. There could be a split character between them like '-' if necessary

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk It would require calling TextRenderer twice with some measurements in-between.  TextRenderer has a static MeasureText function.  Too much code for a comment.  If you need help with it, try posting it as a question.

Comment: ok i'm sure this is the bit of info I was missing thanks a lot !

Comment: I posted it as a question right here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824052/treenode-text-different-colored-words

Thanks for your help