# Treenode text different colored words

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, treeview, treenode

I have a `TreeView` and each of it's `Node.Text` has two words.
The first and second words should have different colors. I'm already changing the color of the text with the `DrawMode` properties and the `DrawNode` event but I can't figure out how to split the `Node.Text` in two different colors. Someone pointed out I could use `TextRenderer.MeasureText` but I have no idead how/where to use it.

Someone has an idea ?

---

**Code :**

```
formload()
{
  treeView1.DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
}

private void treeView1_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e) 
{
Color nodeColor = Color.Red;
if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) != 0)
  nodeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;

 TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics,
                    e.Node.Text,
                    e.Node.NodeFont,
                    e.Bounds,
                    nodeColor,
                    Color.Empty,
                    TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your code?

Comment: In winforms it's not possible, you'd have to use an image.

Comment: @MrFox It is FAR from impossible

Comment: This is possible in winforms if he wants to change the fore color but he must clarify first if this is WinForms , WPF, etc...

Comment: it is winforms I added the tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private void treeView1_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] texts = e.Node.Text.Split();
        using (Font font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Regular))
        {
            using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(texts[0], font, brush, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top);
            }

            using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue))
            {
                SizeF s = e.Graphics.MeasureString(texts[0], font);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(texts[1], font, brush, e.Bounds.Left + (int)s.Width, e.Bounds.Top);
            }
        }
    }
```

You must manage `State` of node to do appropriated actions.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, my mistake see updated version. There is no necessary to measure space size because it already contains in `texts[0]`.

Comment: Genius !! There is a slight problem with the highlight that doesn't highlight the whole text. But i'll figure out how to correct this.

Just one more thing. Is there a way I could catch a node with a single word in it ? (crashes the program on the last line) because it's a rare but possible outcome.

Comment: If you tried it with your program maybe you encountered this glitch(will post in another question) I implemented something similar to the solution you gave me one week ago and had a graphic glitch where the node does not draw at the right place. That's why I asked today again but the glitch is still here.

Comment: the question is here thanks !! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825167/multicolor-treeview-draw-glitch