# Treeview draw glitch

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, treeview

I implemented a multicolor system for each of my `TreeView` nodes. But everytime I expand a child node, it expends but also paints the node over my rootNode (image 2 and 3). The code is from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824052/treenode-text-different-colored-words) and this is what the bug looks like

[image]

If I decide to close every node and re-expand the glitch is gone.(image 4)

The problem Seems to be with the `Bounds` that's why the draw isn't at the right place.
Any idea why ?

---

```
  private void treeView1_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
  {
    string[] texts = e.Node.Text.Split();
    using (Font font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Regular))
    {
        using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(texts[0], font, brush, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top);
        }

        using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue))
        {
            SizeF s = e.Graphics.MeasureString(texts[0], font);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(texts[1], font, brush, e.Bounds.Left + (int)s.Width, e.Bounds.Top);
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Interesting... What is the value of treeView1.DrawMode, and that of e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top, and s.Width when drawing the node?

Comment: The drawMode is TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText

Comment: That's correct. And what are the values of the variables I mentioned?

Comment: I can't check the value. I put a breakpoint so everytime I enter the treeview it breaks before I can expand

Comment: Unless you know I way I could check the value without the breakpoint

Comment: Use Debug.WriteLine or Trace.WriteLine from System.Diagnostics. These print a message to VS console.

Comment: Bounds Left = 21 Top = 0  ////
Bounds = X = 21,Y=0 , Width = 84, Height = 18

Comment: Reviving old thread because root cause is hard to find in docs. Draw node is not only called to draw a node but also if you click expand etc. If you don't want to draw over top left corner, examine bounds and exit sub if they don't correspond with a node label location (for OwnerDrawText)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drawing glitch seems to be an accurate description.

You can try this work around by subscribing to the AfterExpand event:

```
void treeView1_AfterExpand(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) {
  treeView1.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Invalidate() just tells the control to redraw itself.  It doesn't really fix the Microsoft issue, and it might end up causing a little bit of flicker since it needs to draw all the nodes again.

Comment: yes I saw the flicker. But unless there is a way to fix the glitch I will do with that for the moment

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk No experience if this works, but it might be worth trying: [Double-buffered Tree and List views](http://dev.nomad-net.info/articles/double-buffered-tree-and-list-views)

Answer (score 0):

Just Make Sure To Use :
"**BeginUpdate()**" and "**EndUpdate()**" Everytime You Populate the TreeView

The "**EndUpdate()**"<- Is the Most Important thing to Get Rid this Kind of Glitch!

Good Luck! :)

Cheers,
J